# Can I modify a program's memory when it's runtime on Linux?

Tags: linux, memory

I known following things:

```
/proc/$pid/mem   (memory struct of this program)
/proc/$pid/maps
```

Usaually, I use gdb, for example:

```
$ gdb --pid [pid]
(gdb) set {int}0x83040 = 4
```

At first, I guess that maybe gdb opens /proc/$pid/mem file and update it,
so I make a test... I use vim with sudo privilege to open this file but I still can not update the /proc/$pid/men file.

Can anybody tell me how to update the memory of the another program in runtime on Linux? Which file of the system I can update?

My ptrace code:

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{   
    int pid = 23587;
    // int ret = ptrace(PTRACE_SEIZE, pid, NULL, NULL); // or PTRACE_SEIZE if you don't want to suspend the process
    // printf("%d\n", ret);
    int data = 100;
    int res = ptrace(PTRACE_POKEDATA, pid, 999999, &data);
    printf("%d\n", res);
    printf("123\n");
    perror("Error: ");
    return 0;
}
```

But I got message

```
$ sudo ./aa
-1
123
Error: : No such process
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the [ptrace()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) system call for this.

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
...
ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL); // or PTRACE_SEIZE if you don't want to suspend the process
int data = 4;
ptrace(PTRACE_POKEDATA, pid, 0x83040, &data);
```

Comment: Maybe I can search or scan memory value of memory address by read /proc/$pid/mem, then update it by ptrace with address?

Comment: Yes, certainly. And you can use `/proc/$pid/map` to find the addresses of the areas you want to modify.

Comment: Sorry I don't know why i ptrace pockdata always return -1?

Comment: When a system call returns `-1`, `errno` contains the reason. Use `perror()` to display the error message. This is basic Unix programming.

Comment: It shows "No such process", but I use ps aux display theses message:
"scott    23587  0.0  0.2 930188 16340 pts/3    Sl+  11:38   0:01 node". my target pid is 23587.

Comment: Not sure why. Add your code to the question.

Comment: I have updated my question content, I don'k know why it can't find my process id.

Comment: I have make it work fine. Thanks.

Comment: You have to call `perror` before calling `printf`, because that might (and usually does) change `errno`.